# How to return an array from stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I need to return an array from stored procedure. And at client side,finally need to retrieve the data by using c# and ado.net.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_testing]

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @ARRAY TABLE(sno int,id nvarchar(50)

INSERT @ARRAY(sno,id) values(1,'v123')
INSERT @ARRAY(sno,id) values(2,'v124')
INSERT @ARRAY(sno,id) values(3,'v124')
END
```

This @Array table need to be returned and to be retrieved to the client side

Comment: And what have you tried? What specific difficulties did you encounter?

Comment: you can use XML as a output parameter or use table value function in this situation.

Comment: i am trying to return this array as return @array but its not doing

Comment: @Vids you can only `return` an integer expression;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@ARRAY` is not an array: it is a table. The mechanism for obtaining a table is simple and well-practiced:

```
select * from @ARRAY
```

To get that at the client, use either ExecuteReader or something like a DataTable if it makes you happy. Or something like dapper:

```
var arr = connection.Query(
    "usp_testing", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)
    .Select(row => Tuple.Create((int)row.sno, (string)row.id)).ToArray();
```

which is an array of tuples.

Answer (score 2):

```
create procedure strange_procedure as
begin

DECLARE @ARRAY TABLE(id int not null identity primary key, value varchar(50))

insert into @ARRAY (value) values ('This value')

select  *  from @ARRAY


end
```